# SQL Query for first part of a code for an API R script

Tags: sql, r, ckan

I am currently using the NHS' prescribing data API to find all the prescriptions of a certain class of drugs. There is an available script, here, which has instructions to pull out data of a single drug, but when I amend the SQL query to look instead for any drug of a given class (denoted by the first four digits, e.g. 0403, 'antidepressant drugs') the script doesn't work.

The script is available here: https://github.com/nhsbsa-data-analytics/open-data-portal-api/blob/master/open-data-portal-api.R

If I amend the following:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM `", 
    month, "` 
WHERE 
    1=1 
AND pco_code = '", pco_code, "' 
AND bnf_chemical_substance = '", bnf_chemical_substance, "'
"
```

)

to e.g.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM `", 
    month, "` 
WHERE 
    1=1 
AND pco_code = '", pco_code, "' 
AND bnf_chemical_substance LIKE '0403%'
"
```

)

This script does not give the required results. How can I have it pull out all the items starting with those digits, rather than an exact code?

Comment: You could try `AND SUBSTR(bnf_chemical_substance,1,4)='0403'`

Comment: Or you can use `pco_code like '", pco_code, "%'` (I don't know if the API supports full SQL syntax like that, I'm not familiar with it).